# SQLAlchemy (postgres) cast time difference to (integer) days

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am running a query (postgres) which creates a temporary column `grp` dividing the time difference between `event_time` and `start_date` (a `datetime` object) into time periods of given length.

```
date = func.date_trunc('day', M.event_time)
session.query(..., ((date - start_date) / period_length).label('grp'))
       .filter(..., date >= start_date)
       .group_by('grp', ...)
```

This works fine as long as `period_length = 1`, but if it is 2, for example, the result is a `timedelta` which has half days `datetime.timedelta(days=2, seconds=43200)`.
How do I cast this to integer **before** `group_by` to get my expected result?

Comment: Do really want an integer as your `timedelta` is resolving to `2.5` days. As example `td1 = (d2-d1)/2` yields `datetime.timedelta(days=3, seconds=43200)`. To get days: `td1.total_seconds()/86400` yields `3.5` days.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver (1) 3.5 days is not an *integer*; (2) this isn't what I get on my computer `today - yesterday = datetime.timedelta(days=1)` but `(today - yesterday) / 86400 = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)` and divided by 2 `datetime.timedelta(microseconds=500000)`. I need an int to serve as a group ID, so if `date_step` is 3 than I get the same int for 3 consecutive days. The raw query `(occurred_at::date - '{start_date}'::date) / {date_step}` returns what I want - I just cannot figure out how to do the same with ORM.

Comment: 1) I know 3.5 is not an integer. I was illustrating that dividing a period by a number can result in non-integer results. The issue being how do you deal with that round/not round? If round round up/round down? If not round then what? 2) Your date math is wrong. What you are looking for is `(dt2 - dt1).total_seconds()/86400/2 0.5`. Where `0.5` is number of days. This then gets us back to 1) and how do you want deal with it for grouping purposes?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver basically `floor` or `modulo`; for a period `n` the group is the whole number of the division, e.g. n=4 then diff_days of {0,1,2,3} are group 1, {4,5,6,7} are group 2 and so on. Issue is that I cannot use the `cast` func because I have a `BinaryExpression` not a `timedelta` when `cast` is evaluated.

Comment: `(dt2 - dt1).total_seconds()/86400/2` yields a `float`. You will need to add to your question the exact code you are using along with the traceback.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the code is exactly as in the question (minus irrelevant filters and such). `((date - start_date) / period_length` is a `BinaryExpression` so using `cast` is not possible. The entry in the row returned from DB is a `timedelta` which I can divide and cast, but I want the grouping to be done DB-side.

Comment: Use `((date - start_date).total_seconds() / period_length`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver unfortunately that doesn't work because when the expression `date - start_date` is evaluated. The error is `AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'total_seconds'`. This is the same error for `cast` or any other operation I tried.